# Getting the first line of a file with java

Tags: java, file

I am trying to get the first line of a file with java and I am not sure why it is not working or why I am getting the error i am getting. This is the first time I have tried this in java.

Error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 16
    at getSum.main(getSum.java:33)
```

Code

```
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
public class getSum {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
            File file = new File("path/InputArray.txt");
            FileInputStream fis = null;
            BufferedInputStream bis = null;
            DataInputStream dis = null;
            String line = null;
            try{
                fis = new FileInputStream(file);
                bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);
                dis = new DataInputStream(bis);

                while(dis.available() != 0){
                    line = dis.readLine();
                }
            }catch (FileNotFoundException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }catch (IOException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            String[] splitLine = line.split("\\s+");
            int[] numbers = new int[splitLine.length];

            for(int i = 0; i< line.length(); i++){
                try{
                    numbers[i] = Integer.parseInt(splitLine[i]);
                }catch(NumberFormatException nfe){};
            }


           int amount = 0;
           System.out.print(numbers.length);
           /*amount = sumArray(0,numbers.length,numbers.length,numbers);
           System.out.print("Total: " + amount);*/
    }
```

Comment: What is the line that produces this error ?

Comment: @CyrilleKarmann obviously the one with `numbers[i] = Integer.parseInt(splitLine[i])`

Comment: Have you tried running this in a debugger and see what the data looks like after the split?

Comment: Please don't catch the NFEs without treatment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look at this:

```
int[] numbers = new int[splitLine.length];
for(int i = 0; i< line.length(); i++){
    try{
        numbers[i] = Integer.parseInt(splitLine[i]);
    }catch(NumberFormatException nfe){};
}
```

You're using `i` from 0 to `line.length()`... which isn't the same as `splitLine.length`. I suspect you meant:

```
for (int i = 0; i< splitLine.length; i++) {
```

At that point, as both `numbers` and `splitLine` have the same length, you definitely won't get an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Answer (score 0):

I think your for loop condition is wrong. I think you should check for splitLine.length().

```
for(int i = 0; i< splitLine.length(); i++){
     try{
          numbers[i] = Integer.parseInt(splitLine[i]);
     }catch(NumberFormatException nfe){};
}
```